# Overwrite an object function from an external script before it is called

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a Greasemonkey script or Userscript to fix a bug in a website, which deals with an erroneous function of an object. I can fix the problem manually, by adding a breakpoint at the line of code which generates the function prototype, and manually overwriting the function prototype using the js console. However, I don't think there is any way to do this with code. The external script is loaded at the end of the html body, but the problem code is executed within that same script.

Is there any way to somehow inject javascript code into the page, so that when this Ft.prototype.J is created, I can immediately modify it? The problem is that the code is also obfuscated and minified, so I'm not sure what half of it does.

Here is the basic rundown of the code:

```
//What does this do?????
function A(a, b) {
    function c() {}
    c.prototype = b.prototype;
    a.f = b.prototype;
    a.prototype = new c;
    a.prototype.constructor = a
}

function Ft(a, b) {
    $.call(this, b);
    //some stuff
}
//doing something with jQuery?
A(Ft, $);
Ft.prototype.J = function (a) {
   //modifies the DOM content
};
//Code soon after that calls some object.J
```

If I add in the line of code `Ft.prototype.J = function() {} //my own function`, into my greasemonkey script, it gives me back the error, as expected, `Ft not defined`. But, if I execute that line at the end of the load, the broken function has already been run, and the DOM is already infected.

Thanks.

Comment: `A` is the common `inherit` function, however I'm quite sure it does not work with jQuery

Comment: Oh I see now thanks. This is actually code from the Google Play website, so I hope they're doing it right...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can perform some magic with getters/setters and [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), since the function is declared globally:

```
(function() {
    var Ft;
    function myJ() {
        // do whatever YOU want to do
    }
    Object.defineProperty(window, "Ft", { // use unsafeWindow in GM?
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: true,
        get: function() { return Ft; },
        set: function(n) {
            // Hah, we've catched the function declaration!
            Ft = n;

            // just making it non-writable would lead to an exception
            Object.defineProperty(Ft.prototype, "J", {
                get: function() { return myJ; },
                set: function() { /* ignore it! */ }
            });
        }
    });
})();
```

Now if someone executes the code you've posted in your question, the setters will be invoked and you can do with the values what you want.

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but the object has many functions, and it seems like this one only handle the case if there is one prototype. Also, for testing purposes, I added in a `console.log("test")` and nothing came up.

Comment: Have you tried the `unsafeWindow` I mentioned in the comment?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but you can basically write a timer code that will check if Ft object is available and then modify the function, like

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (Ft) {
       Ft.prototype.J = function() {} //my own function
       clearInterval(interval)
    }
}, 0);
```